# Play YouTube videos faster than 2x on Android

Tags: video, youtube

I know that it is possible to play YouTube videos faster than 2x on laptop and desktop using extensions available on Google Chrome. However, these can't be downloaded on Android device.

I have already searched for this on Google and YouTube and some videos suggested using another app which plays those videos faster. But all the apps I have downloaded so far either only allow up to 2x speed or can speed up only those video files which are already downloaded on device, and I can't find downloaded YouTube videos on device (it only opens in YouTube).

Is there any way of playing YouTube videos faster on Android?

Comment: [NewPipe](https://newpipe.net/) can fast forward up to 3x times. You can also try Kiwi Browser on Android. It is Chromium based, and supports web extensions. So your Chrome extensions might work on Kiwi Browser. Let us know how it turns out for you.

Comment: @Firelord thanks, newpipe can successfully play youtube videos upto 3x speed. I wish i could go faster

Comment: @Firelord extensions can be downloaded on kiwi browser and they also are also seen while playing YouTube videos, but the problem is that the extension which had been using before operated on keys pressed by keyboard and i am unable to do that in android. Please suggest another usable extension

Answer (score 0):

On Google Play, there is an app called [Video Speed Control Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yh.vscb). It lets you go up to 10x speed.